# Microkingdom USB headset not playing sound properly

Tags: windows-7, usb, performance, audio, headset

My headset is playing sound that should only be playing on the left side on both left and right sides of the headset, but sound that's coming from the right is on the right side.

It's also odd that when I'm playing Minecraft, all the footsteps and mob sounds are playing on the left side, the ambient sound is playing normally, and when I start up my siren in-game it only plays on the right side. No mater where I look, it doesn't change like my right ear piece is playing what the left and right would hear.

Anyone know whats going on?

Comment: Does this fault only happen on the minecraft? What if you play music?

Comment: it plays the vocals on the left side and most of the bass I've bin playing minecraft and it works just fine but when i use the usb headset

Comment: Sorry for another question, can you test on 'normal jack' headphones (instead of USB)?

Comment: yeah it works fine with a jack headset

Comment: And any fault shown in device manager? Do you have another USB headphone to test? Can you make sure your headset drivers are up to date, as is the chip-set on board and the audio drivers.

Comment: i don't have another usb headset and im not sure what you mean about "headset drivers"? my usb headset didn't come with a installer disc

Comment: Find it in device manager, click on properties and see if you can update the driver. Also, see if you have anything in Windows Updates related to either the board, audio driver or USB, or even the device in question.

Comment: I have three based system updates and a service pack, should I install them? And the usb headset is up-to-date from what the devise manager says

Comment: So, did nothing appear in device manager? As for Windows Updates, just make sure you have done a restore point first and make sure you know what happens to your system if you do an update (I don't want to be accountable if it breaks anything :) ) although if it was my system, I would update all.